# Lift, Flot, & JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, lift, flot

I'm new to the Lift framework, and for the past couple of days I've been playing around with the Flot widget.  I really like the fact that I have a facade to the Flot javascript written in Scala.  However, I ran into some issues when I tried to add more interactive features to the graph.

What I'm attempting to do is allow the user to zoom in on data-points in the graph.  Basically I'm trying to accomplish this example, but in lift:  http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/zooming.html.

The meat of the zoom is handled by this javascript:

```
 $("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
    // do some checks on the ranges...

    // do the zooming
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), getData(...),
                  $.extend(true, {}, options, {
                      xaxis: { min: ranges.xaxis.from, max: ranges.xaxis.to },
                      yaxis: { min: ranges.yaxis.from, max: ranges.yaxis.to }
                  }));
```

What's the best way to do this in Lift?  In the code above I'm generating the plot in pure-javascript, but the flot-widget is supposed to do this for me.  It seems incorrect to have that code twice, once using the Flot-widget and once again here in raw javascript.  I'm not sure if I should move the chunk of code above into Scala.  Futhermore, I haven't found any documentation on how to do a jQuery bind in the Scala DSL.  Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

One final niggle...
The jquery.flot.selection plugin is required to do zooming, so I had to add that into my Lift project manually.  That's fine, except that the jquery.flot.js is built-in automatically.  When I added the flot.selection plugin, my plugin version was too new for the jquery.flot.js included with Lift.  I had to go spelunking through the jars to figure out which version of the selection plugin I needed.

I've gotten burned by maven quite a number of times where one library included another library automatically for me...I realize JavaScript may be different but I'm still gun-shy when it comes to libraries including other libraries.

Okay...I'll stop ranting now :)
Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on the Lift platform aspect, but for flot itself, there is no way around the need to re-call plot with nearly the same set of options and data.

If you were writing the whole thing yourself, I'd say just write a function that takes the ranges object and calls plot for you, and call that on page load and in the `plotselected` function.  As it is, two calls is your only decent option.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The problem isn't really with flot so much as with the Lift integration of flot.  Right now I'm calling flot with a Lift API - and it looks like really the only way to do zoom is to use the native Flot API.  I'm thinking I'm going to have to abandon the Lift API and use pure javascript (basically do what you described above).